# Не понимаю почему не выводится результат

Tags: javascript

```js
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {
  var numbers = [2, 4, 5, 6];
  numbers.sort(a, b => a - b);
  console.log(newNum);
  return newNum = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Задача такая: надо было из массива получить 2 наименьших числа и сложить их.
может я не понимаю правильно как работает console.log();
но он вроде и до return и после функции не выдает правильные результат. я обьявляла уже переменную newNum. var newNum = 0; и все равно ничего( помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Во первых, функцию надо вызвать `sumTwoSmallestNumbers([1,2,3,4])`, сейчас вы ее объявили и все. После return код работать не будет. Что бы вывести результат работы функции, его и надо законсолить `console.log(sumTwoSmallestNumbers([2,3,4,5]))`

Comment: спасибо большое, все исправила

Comment: Нужный результат удалось достичь?

Comment: да, спасибо большое!